# Create a table by combining one column from another table in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping, foreign-key-relationship

So after some research, I could not find something relevant.

I use one table as below:

```
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long productId;

   // other irrelevant columns and code goes here
}
```

Now, I want to create another table that it goes like:

[image: table columns and what rows I want to show]

To make that, I tried something like this by following other examples or samples:

```
@Table(name="combined_products")
public class CombinedProducts {

   @EmbeddedId
   protected CombinedProductsPK bridgeId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "product_1", referencedColumnName = "product_id"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "product_2", referencedColumnName = "product_id")
   })

   @Column(name = "notes")
   private String notes;

   public ProductMatrix() {
      bridgeId = new CombinedProductsPK();
   }

   // irrelevant code again
}
```

and the CombinedProductsPK:

```
@Embeddable
public class CombinedProductsPK implements Serializable {

   public Long product_1;
   public Long product_2;

   public CombinedProductsPK() {}

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj) {
         return true;
      }
      CombinedProductsPK b = (CombinedProductsPK)obj;
      if (b == null) {
         return false;
      }
      return b.product_1.equals(product_1) && b.product_2.equals(product_2);
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return (int)(product_1 + product_2);
   }
}
```

and all seems to work perfect.

BUT, my problem is, when I take a look at the database and specific to the combined_products table, there is **no** FOREIGN_KEY constraint. Is there any way to describe this constraint in Java, or I must manually, in the Java part, take care of this??

*This is how my table looks like in the MySQLWorkbench*

```
CREATE TABLE `combined_products` (
  `product_1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_1`,`product_2`)
)
```

*I'm in a dead end here, so maybe I follow a wrong route. Every recommendation is accepted! Thanks in advance...*

Answer (score 0):

i didn't got what you mean. but maybe you need to try @JoinTable for that ?

[enter link description here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Example_of_a_ManyToMany_relationship_annotation)

i hope it helps.